# Probability of dependent events over time, when probability approaches 1.

Tags: probability, sequences-and-series

I have a probability problem.  Let's say there's a function that determines probability such that the probability of event X happening is

$$F(x) = 0.9 + 0.09\sum_{n=0}^x 10^{-n}$$

For event F(2) to happen, event F(1) must happen.  So, for instance, if F(0) happens (0.99), then we move to F(1).  If that happens (0.999) then so on, etc.  I know that the probability approaches 1 as it goes to infinity.  My question is, what's the probability of ~F(x) happening?  I know that it isn't 0, but it seems that it would approach 0, which doesn't seem to make sense.  As you add more steps, wouldn't it become increasingly likely that ~F(x) would happen?

Would 10^-(x+2) be the inverse, e.g. ~F(x)?

Comment: Please do not use pictures for critical portions of your post. Pictures may not be legible, cannot be searched and are not view-able to some, such as those who use screen readers.

Comment: Your terminology is a bit confusing. I think you have a *random variable* $X$ that can take nonnegative integer values, and you have a *CDF function* $F_X(x)=P[X\leq x]$ that satisfies $$F_X(x) = 0.9 + 0.09\sum_{n=0}^x 10^{-n} \quad \forall x \in \{0, 1, 2, ...\}$$ So then $F_X(2)=P[X\leq 2] = P[X=0]+P[X=1]+P[X=2]$.

Comment: I apologize of both counts.  For the picture, I tried typing the formula out, but the summation symbol couldn't be copied, and I couldn't find the way to properly format it.  For Michael, isn't it multiplied, rather than added? Since they Event(2) is dependent on Event(1)?